# How to delete IMarkers after editor closed ( or why isnt the IMarker.TRANSIENT property working)?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a custom editor in Eclipse and just integrated custom error recognition. Now I'm facing a strange issue: I can add Markers to my editor that get displayed all fine, I can also delete them while the editor is running.

**What doesn't work:** When I close my editor I want the markers to disappear/get deleted.

What I'm doing right now, is

- creating the Markers with the transient property set like this: `marker.setAttribute(IMarker.TRANSIENT, true);` This doesn't seem to change anything though.
- trying to delete all Annotations via the source viewers **annotation-model**. This doesn't work, cause when I try to hook into my editors `dispose()` method or add a `DisposeListener` to my **sourceviewers textwidget**, the sourceviewer already has been disposed of and `getSourceViewer().getAnnotationModel();` returns `null`.

My `deleteMarkers` method:

```
private void deleteMarkers() {
        IAnnotationModel anmod = getSourceViewer().getAnnotationModel();
        Iterator<Annotation> it = anmod.getAnnotationIterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            SimpleMarkerAnnotation a = (SimpleMarkerAnnotation) it.next();
            anmod.removeAnnotation(a);

            try {
                a.getMarker().delete();
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated ^^

Comment: Do they have to be IMarkers? If they only exist while the editor is running you can just use annotations that aren't markers.

Comment: IMarker.TRANSIENT means the marker isn't saved across sessions, but doesn't mean it is deleted when the editor exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook into your editor close event, get a reference to the IResource for the editor (i believe you get can that on IEditorInput) and call IResource#deleteMarkers() on the relevant resource which will delete them when you close your editor. By design eclipse does not delete markers when editors are closed.

Here is some reference:
[http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html#deleteMarkers(java.lang.String, boolean, int)](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html#deleteMarkers(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20int))

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot !
That's 100% what I was looking for ^^

Comment: Sweet, glad it helped, I know the frustration of trying to figure some of this eclipse stuff out.